# Discord.py move all members from one voice channel to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I made two working bot commands, one that get id's from users connected to a voice channel and the other one move single members to another channel.
How can i automate the process? I need to move every member without typing the username on discord chat

Thanks in advance

---

```
@bot.command()
async def move(ctx, channel : discord.VoiceChannel, *members: discord.Member):
    for member in members:
        await member.move_to(channel)


@bot.command()
async def people(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(ID_HERE)
    member_ids = list(channel.voice_states.keys())
    return member_ids

#*members should get member_ids
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create another command from which you call the other two functions:

```py
@bot.command()
async def moveAll(ctx, channel:discord.VoiceChannel):
    members_connected = await people(ctx) #Get the people
    for member_id in people_connected:
        member = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(member_id)
        await member.move_to(channel)
```

Comment: `async def`: typo

Comment: gives this error when executed: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'move_to'

Comment: @Alex it should work now, I edited it.

Comment: Awesome, really appreciated!